# How can I read this JPEG from an iPhone? neither PIL nor OpenCV can do it

Tags: python, opencv, python-imaging-library, jpeg

I am trying to open an iPhone image in a Jupyter notebook. This is the location of my image on my hard drive: `/Users/admin/work/img_2581.jpg`; this is the location of my Jupyter notebook: `/Users/admin/work/Untitled.ipynb`. However, I am unable to load the image onto the Jupyter notebook.

Image Path: `path = '/Users/admin/work/img_2581.jpg'`

Notebook location: `/Users/admin/work/Untitled.ipynb`

I first tried using OpenCV to open the image on the Jupyter notebook. Here's what I did:

OpenCV image read: `img = cv2.imread(path)`

I tried to print the shape of the image: `print(img.shape)`. However, I received the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'shape'
```

To check for the correct path of the image, I used a simple Python `open()` statement:

```
f = open("../work/img_2581.jpg", "r")
print(f)
```

Output: `<_io.TextIOWrapper name='../work/img_2581.jpg' mode='r' encoding='UTF-8'>`

Seeing that OpenCV did not work, I tried using Pillow:

```
from PIL import Image

img = Image.open(path)
```

The following exception occurred when I tried Pillow:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnidentifiedImageError                    Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [14], in <cell line: 3>()
      1 from PIL import Image
----> 3 img = Image.open(path)

File ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PIL/Image.py:3283, in open(fp, mode, formats)
   3281     warnings.warn(message)
   3282 msg = "cannot identify image file %r" % (filename if filename else fp)
-> 3283 raise UnidentifiedImageError(msg)

UnidentifiedImageError: cannot identify image file '/Users/admin/work/img_2581.jpg'
```

I saw on this website that a possible problem was that the image has been corrupted. However, I am able to open it without any issues.

My questions are as follows:

(1) In OpenCV, why is `img` taking on the value of `None` when the image I am importing exists?

(2) What is causing `UnidentifiedImageError` in Pillow?

(3) How can I fix these issues?

Comment: your picture is either a strange JPEG or not a JPEG at all. Apple could have put different data in the file and merely called it a "jpeg" so as to not scare their users. please present this file (not on an image hosting service because they convert images!) or use a hex editor and show us the first few hex lines of the file.

Comment: Yes, you are right - I checked the meta data of the file. Changing format via preview did the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seem to be two possibilities:

- either OpenCV/PIL cannot find the image, or
- they can find it but cannot read it.

I'll look at each possibility in a separate section.

---

**In case OpenCV/PIL cannot find your image...**

The simplest thing to do is work out what directory your Jupyter notebook is running in, so use:

```
!pwd
```

Then you can work out the ***relative*** path to your image - that is a path that does NOT start with a slash.

So, if your notebook is running in `/Users/admin`, you will need to open `work/img_2581.jpg` without a leading slash.

If your notebook is running in `/Users/admin/work`, you will need to open `img_2581.jpg` without a leading slash.

If your notebook is running in `/Users/admin/work/someMadDirectory`, you will need to open `../img_2581.jpg` without a leading slash because `..` means *"one level higher"*.

---

**In case OpenCV/PIL can find your image, but cannot read it...**

It is possible that your image is either not a JPEG at all, or is a JPEG with unusual characteristics (such as being 12-bit instead of 8-bit) or is say JPEG2000.

The simplest way to test if it is a JPEG on Linux/macOS without installing any special software is with:

```
file img_2581.jpg        # or "!file img_2581.jpg" inside Jupyter
```

If you don't have `file` available, `exiftool` is an excellent way to examine images, so I would suggest:

```
exiftool img_2581.jpg    # or "!exiftool img_2581.jpg" inside Jupyter
```

If you have neither `file` nor `exiftool`, you can upload your image to https://hexed.it and copy the first few lines and paste them into your question so we can check them.

Comment: I used `!pwd` to find out my CWD, and my notebook is running in `/Users/admin/work`. I modified the OpenCV command to `img = cv2.imread('img_2581.jpg')`. However, `img` is still `None`.

Comment: Ok, so if you are in that directory, you should be able to run `!ls -l img_2581.jpg` and see the size and permissions of your image?

Comment: This is what I get: `-rw-rw-rw-@ 1 admin  staff  215527 Feb  3 18:34 img_2581.jpg`

Comment: Mmmm! Try `!file img_2581.jpg` to see if it is a 12-bit JPEG or something that will confuse OpenCV or PIL.

Comment: Failing that, try running `exiftool img_2581.jpg` to see if that tells us anything new. You'll need to edit the results into your question rather than put them in the comments because there'll be too much.

Comment: Or you can read the file as binary and print the first 30 bytes with `open('img_2581.jpg', 'rb').read(30)`

Comment: Here's what I got after running `open('img_2581.jpg', 'rb').read(30)`: 

`b'\x00\x00\x00 ftypheic\x00\x00\x00\x00mif1miafMiHBhe'`

Comment: Also... there's a problem: when I ran `!file img_2581.jpg`: `img_2581.jpg: ISO Media, HEIF Image HEVC Main or Main Still Picture Profile`. I changed the file extension, but it's still a HEIC! I'll try to change the format and let you know the results.

Comment: You can convert it with **ImageMagick** in your Terminal using `magick YOURFILE output.jpg`